# Vuetify v-autocomplete have issue

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I using vuetify.js on laravel project.
and I create [station][verhicle][take a time] form like this.

[image]

its simple form. but ...
station select box is used v-autocomplete component.
so it seems that the input tag is automatically embedded like this.

[image]

this input tag is unnecessary.
I expect return one array.

Is there any good way?
thank you

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-row dense>
      <v-col sm="4">
        <v-autocomplete
          v-model="StationModel"
          :items="stationsSon"
          :search-input.sync="search"
          item-text="name"
          item-value="id"
          name="station_id[]"
          label="station"
          clearable
          hide-details
          hide-selected
          outlined
        >

          <template v-slot:selection="{ item,selected }">
            <span>{{ item.routell_name + item.name }}</span>
          </template>

          <template v-slot:item="{ item }">
            <v-list-item-content>
              <v-list-item-title v-text="item.name"></v-list-item-title>
              <v-list-item-subtitle v-text="item.routell_name"></v-list-item-subtitle>
            </v-list-item-content>
          </template>

        </v-autocomplete>
      </v-col>
    
      <v-col sm="4">
        <v-select
          name="verhicle_id[]"
          :items="verhiclesSon"
          item-value="id"
          item-text="name"
          label="verhicle"
          outlined
          clearable
        >
      </v-select>
      </v-col>
      
      <v-col sm="4">
        <v-text-field
          name="take_time[]"
          type="number"
          :rules="[v => v && v.length <= 2 || 'Warn:2 charactor']"
          label="take a time"
          outlined
        >
        </v-text-field>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
  export default {

    data: () => ({

      stationsDefault: [],
      StationModel: null,
      search: null,
      tab: null,

    }),

    watch: {
      model (val) {
        if (val != null) this.tab = 0;
        else this.tab = null;
      },
      search (val) {
        if (this.stationsDefault.length > 0) return;
      },
    },

    props:{
      stationsSon:{
        type: Array
      },
      verhiclesSon:{
        type: Array
      },
    },


    methods:{
      snipeDown: function(){
        const target = document.getElementsByClassName('v-select__selections');
        document.removeChild(target("input"));
      }
    },

  };
</script>
```

Comment: what do you mean by return one array?

Comment: Hi Nilesh

If I add attribute name propaty to v-autocomplete.
The input tag is displayed twice.

0 => null,
1 => 1,
2 => null,
3 => 2,
and more...

but Im not need first input tag.

0 => 1,
1 => 2,
2 => 3,
and more..

I'm sorry, my English is not good

Comment: Please share some code...otherwise very difficult to help you

Comment: I pasted the code for component.
thank you